# Validate combination of two fields in a table against allowed combinations in another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
Table A: Customer, Item

Table B: Customer, Cust.Group

Table C: Item, Item.Group

Table D: Cust.group, Item.Group
```

I want to validate combinations in Table A against allowed combinations in Table D. My problem is that both fields relate to D via/by Table B and Table C.

(Table B and C have multiple returns for one query, as both Customers and Items can be in several groups, meaning that entries in Table A can validate to multiple combinations)

How/Can this be solved by simple selects and joins? Or do I need a little more complexity with variables, loops etc.?

Comment: What are the keys and column names should not have a .  ?

Comment: Sorry for the notation, the code I am boxing with is more complex than this, I cooked it down to this example because it was the essence of my problem, and I didn't think the keys played any role. Next time I will make my examples more correctly in line with the SQL syntax, thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this should be the valid rows

```
select * 
from tA 
join tB 
  on tB.cust = tA.cust 
join tC 
  on tC.item = tA.item 
join tD 
  on tD.CustGroup tB.CustGroup 
 and tD.ItemGroup tC.ItemGroup
```

This is the invalid rows

```
select * 
from tA 
join tB 
  on tB.cust = tA.cust 
join tC 
  on tC.item = tA.item 
left join tD 
  on tD.CustGroup tB.CustGroup 
 and tD.ItemGroup tC.ItemGroup 
where tD.CustGroup is null
```

Comment: Thank you paparazzo, it seems to work perfectly, the last code with the invalid rows helped me a lot, I don't know why I didn't think of the left join.